# How to do an equation with message.content

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to do (153 - message.content)//7 + 1
floor divide
My current solution is not working

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from math import floor

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


@bot.event


async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
        return
  if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(floor(153 - int(message.content)/7) + 1))
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you show us the current output of the piece of code you wrote? Is there an error? This is stack overflow, you have to be specific

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Johny John Boy

Comment: I put in 100 I get 8 - If I did the math right

Comment: @Zack VT  I get no error but if I put in 100 I get 139

Comment: It’s more of a matter that I do not know how to write it in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this? You wrote the division inside the brackets, I think you meant to do it outside?

First make sure you import the math module

```
import math
```

```
await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(math.floor((153 - int(message.content))/7 + 1))
```

Comment: If I put in 200

Comment: *100 sry I meant

Comment: Im so confused I’m now getting a syntax error for bot.run below